# Update product attribute via mysql in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a php script that reads a csv file and update the product attribute value 'Costs', However i noticed that when using the code below:

```
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
   $product->setData('cost', $data[COG])->save();
```

It took so long to finish FYI i have 7000k products that updates Qty every 5minutes,

Is there a way to convert that line to a mysql Query which do the work faster? Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow code

```
$store_id = 0;
$attribute_code='cost';
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array($productId),
    array('attribute_code' => $attribute_code),
    $store_id
);
```

Comment: I am looking for a mysql query

Comment: Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/306701/57334  thanks @Jinesh